# How to create and join multiple derived tables in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, azure

I'm pretty new to SQL and am hitting a wall and would really appreciate any help!

I'm using SQL Server in Azure. I have a table called Votes that has the columns:

- arenaId
- eventId
- userId
- vote
- active
- groupA
- groupB

In here, I've got multiple users voting on various events (eventId) which are part of various arenas (arenaId).  The user can belong to either/both/none of groupA,and groupB.  The vote column can have a value of 0,1,2. The active column filters out which vote to count as each user can only cast a single vote per eventId. So if they cast multiple votes, all subsequent votes will have `active=0` and the latest will have `active=1`

Each arena would have multiple events associated with it, but the event is unique to a specific arena.

My goal is to be able to count the types of votes per arena per group.

**Sample Table Setup:**

```
arenaId | eventId | userId | vote | active | groupA | groupB
------------------------------------------------------------
abc123 |   123   |   5    |   0  |    1   |    0   |    0   
abc123 |   124   |   5    |   2  |    1   |    0   |    0   
abc123 |   125   |   5    |   1  |    1   |    0   |    0   
abc123 |   126   |   5    |   1  |    1   |    0   |    0   
------------------------------------------------------------
abc123 |   123   |   6    |   1  |    1   |    1   |    0   
abc123 |   124   |   6    |   1  |    1   |    1   |    0   
abc123 |   125   |   6    |   2  |    1   |    1   |    0   
abc123 |   126   |   6    |   1  |    1   |    1   |    0   
------------------------------------------------------------
abc123 |   123   |   7    |   2  |    1   |    1   |    1   
abc123 |   124   |   7    |   1  |    1   |    1   |    1   
abc123 |   125   |   7    |   2  |    1   |    1   |    1   
abc123 |   126   |   7    |   1  |    1   |    1   |    1   
------------------------------------------------------------
abc123 |   123   |   8    |   2  |    1   |    0   |    1   
abc123 |   124   |   8    |   1  |    1   |    0   |    1   
abc123 |   125   |   8    |   2  |    1   |    0   |    1   
abc123 |   126   |   8    |   2  |    1   |    0   |    1   
------------------------------------------------------------
def321 |   127   |   5    |   1  |    1   |    0   |    0   
def321 |   128   |   5    |   1  |    1   |    0   |    0   
def321 |   129   |   5    |   2  |    1   |    0   |    0   
def321 |   130   |   5    |   0  |    1   |    0   |    0   
------------------------------------------------------------
def321 |   127   |   6    |   0  |    1   |    1   |    0   
def321 |   128   |   6    |   2  |    1   |    1   |    0   
def321 |   129   |   6    |   2  |    1   |    1   |    0   
def321 |   130   |   6    |   1  |    1   |    1   |    0   
------------------------------------------------------------
def321 |   127   |   7    |   1  |    1   |    1   |    1   
def321 |   128   |   7    |   1  |    1   |    1   |    1   
def321 |   129   |   7    |   2  |    1   |    1   |    1   
def321 |   130   |   7    |   2  |    1   |    1   |    1   
------------------------------------------------------------
def321 |   127   |   8    |   2  |    1   |    0   |    1   
def321 |   128   |   8    |   2  |    1   |    0   |    1   
def321 |   129   |   8    |   2  |    1   |    0   |    1   
def321 |   130   |   8    |   2  |    1   |    0   |    1
```

**Desired Result:**

```
arenaId | tVotes0 | tVotes1 | tVotes2 | aVotes0 | aVotes1 | aVotes2 | bVotes0 | bVotes1 | bVotes2
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
abc123  |    1    |    8    |    7    |    0    |    5    |    3    |    0    |    3    |    5
def321  |    2    |    5    |    9    |    1    |    3    |    4    |    0    |    2    |    6
```

`tVotes` is the total votes, not taking into account what group the user is in. So `tVotes0` = total votes of value 0, `tVotes1` = total votes of value 1, `tVotes2` = total votes of value 2. `aVotes` are just the votes cast by users who belong in groupA. `bVotes` are just the votes of users who belong in groupB

So the value in the desired results view, the row with arenaId `abc123` has a value of 1 for `tVotes0` means there was a total count of 1 vote with a value of 0 within that arena. The reason aVotes0 and bVotes0 are 0 is because the user who cast the vote with value 0 was not part of either group A or B.

I can get the result only if I specify an arenaId, doing something like the query below:

```
SELECT (
         SELECT COUNT(eventId) AS voteCount
         FROM (
                SELECT eventId
                FROM Votes
                WHERE arenaId = 'abc123'
                      AND active = 1
                      AND vote = 1
                AND groupA = 1
                GROUP BY userId, eventId
              ) AS t1
       ) AS aVotes1
```

But I'd like to get a result where I can see all the vote summaries per arena:

Thank you all so much in advance!

Comment: I don't think I can understand it without explanation, for example let's start with what is `tVotes0 ...etc` and what those numbers refering to? what is the logic here?

Comment: Yeah there isn't enough explanation to get from the sample data to the desired output. Help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: tVotes is the total votes, not taking into account what group the user is in. so tVotes0 = total votes of value 0, tVotes1 = total votes of value 1, tVotes2 = total votes of value 2.
aVotes are just the votes cast by users who belong in groupA. bVotes are just the votes of users who belong in groupB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    arenaId
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT eventId) as NumberOfEvents
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vote = 0 THEN 1 END) as tVotes0
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vote = 1 THEN 1 END) as tVotes1
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vote = 2 THEN 1 END) as tVotes2
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vote = 0 AND groupA = 1 THEN 1 END) as aVotes0
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vote = 1 AND groupA = 1 THEN 1 END) as aVotes1
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vote = 2 AND groupA = 1 THEN 1 END) as aVotes2
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vote = 0 AND groupB = 1 THEN 1 END) as aVotes0
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vote = 1 AND groupB = 1 THEN 1 END) as aVotes1
    ,COUNT(CASE WHEN vote = 2 AND groupB = 1 THEN 1 END) as aVotes2
FROM
    Votes
WHERE
    active = 1
GROUP BY
    arenaId
```

It really seems like you are more looking to `PIVOT` the data.  There are a few ways you could do that but instead of preparing and then pivoting you can just do it as a single operation using `CONDITIONAL AGGREGATION`.

If you actually have multiple tables involved as I suspect then you could just use the technique with joins.

Here is the example in action so you can see the results: http://rextester.com/SZGGR60834

Comment: Wow, I think that did it. My mind was way off and thinking in a whole different way. Thanks so much!

Comment: @potorik the conditional aggregation technique is extremely powerful for many many scenarios.  but if I can offer advice seeing you stated you are new to sql.  It would be to break your problem down into 2 parts.  First what data you want to actual see/question to answer.  Then second how you want it presented.  If you had thought of aggregating to rows to begin with you could have prepared your results then pivoted them.  The conditional aggregation technique is handy because you can do both in 1 step